# preventing threatened atrocities

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase "preventing threatened atrocities" correct in English?  The quesiton arises because the definition of atrocity is "an extremely cruel, violent, or shocking act" - Such an act is usually threatening rather than (being) threatened.  So the phrase should have been "preventing threatening atrocities". I am not absolutely sure.

> United States support for regime change and the assassination of Muammar Gaddafi in Lybia on the pretext of **preventing threatened atrocities** reeked of hypocricy when stacked against the prolonged US inaction in the face of actual atrocities being perpitrated by governments in Bahrain, Yemen, Syria and elsewhere or fierce internal repression in Saudi Arabia, where Wahhabi extremists continued to fund Al-Qaeda and global jihadis.

> Source: The Untold History of the United States by Oliver Stone (page 600)

Comment: The sense of the phrase is 'preventing atrocities which the Gaddafi regime were threatening to commit'. It doesn't mean that the atrocities 'felt' threatened, if that is how you are reading it.

Comment: I read it as your understanding it.  If "'preventing threatened atrocities" was correct, then "preventing threatening atrocities" would be incorrect. That is the problem.

Comment: The atrocities were not doing the threatening, the Libyan authorities were. '... _preventing [those] atrocities threatened [by Gaddafi]_ ...'

Comment: Passive voice is being used here. The atrocities _were threatened_ by someone (i.e., someone threatened to commit them). I can see how this is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the original

> United States support for regime change and the assassination of Muammar Gaddafi in Lybia on the pretext of preventing threatened atrocities reeked of hypocricy when stacked against the prolonged US inaction ...

We could rewite it as

> United States support for regime change and the assassination of Muammar Gaddafi in Lybia was based on the pretext that they would prevent atrocities which he had threatened. Their support reeked of hypocricy when stacked against the prolonged US inaction ...

I have left the spelling  mistakes as I assume they are in the original text.